# enable to start my workflow on my document library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

i try to start my workflow an alert javascript apprear:
a problem has occurred, reload the page to try again and start the workflow

my workflow is a simple workflow to send an email when a document is just added to the library.
i tested email action (with send a link in email) and it work

Comment: What type of workflow have you created? and in what version, 2010 or 2013?

Comment: custom workflow to send email version 2013

Comment: is it a SharePoint Designer 2013 custom workflow?

Comment: yes i custome it with sharepoint designer 2013 then i publish it to my SP library

Comment: which sharepoint version do you have? foundation?

Comment: sharepoint server version 5 (15.0.0.4420)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a cache issue. Try to flush the DNS cache on your SharePoint Server

> (C:> IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS)

Then recycle your "**Workflow & Service Bus Services**" and then publish the workflow again and hopefully it should work.

Comment: no it doesn't  work, i must have workflow manager frontend installed ?

Answer (score 0):

This may possibly be a master page issue. Set your master page to the defaults (v4.master) and try to set the workflow again.

Once you have created the workflow you can set it back to your preferred master page(s).